# HashMap value being changed to the last object inserted in the List

Tags: java, list, reference, hashmap

When I plot the List, the objects are different, but only the HashMap value are the same as the last inserted in the List.

During the creation (the loop), I tried to plot the HashMap values and it are different. I use it to generate a graph and make some calculations. However, when I add it to the list all values became the same, or every time that I am creating a new object it are changing the HashMap values of all objects within the list.

Here is my code: https://github.com/Willtl/2/tree/master/GAScheduling/src/main/java/uni/lu

In the Main.java, I am creating a new population:

```
Population pop = new Population(jobs, machines, genesPlate, populationSize);
```

In the Population constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < popsize; i++) {
    individuals.add(new Individual(i+1, jobs, machines, genesPlate)); 
}
```

Inside each Individual I am shuffling each ArrayList of the HashMap genesPlate.

```
this.id = id;
this.genesPlate = plate;
this.jobs = jobs;
this.machines = machines;

ArrayList<Job> l1 = null;
// shuffle list of jobs of each machine
for (int i = 0; i < machines.length; i++) {
    l1 = genesPlate.get(machines[i].getId());

    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(l1, new Random(seed));
    genesPlate.put(machines[i].getId(), l1);
} 

System.out.println("Reshuffled: " + genesPlate);

computeFitness();
```

Until here everything is ok. I am plotting and indeed it are shuffled. I use jobs and this genesPlate (random machine sequences) to generate a graph and compute the fitness of each individual.

However, I tryed to comment this code and nothing happened (prob. remains the same). So I think this code is ok.

I am stuck for days in that. I tried everything. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java only has primitive and reference variables.

When you add a reference to a List into a Map, only the reference to the List is copied, not the List it references. If you only create one List and you add it's reference to a Map, there is still only one List object.

To confirm this you can see this by stepping through your code in your debugger to see that your Map most likely has all it's values pointing to the same List.

Comment: So what should I do? I need each object in the list with its own HashMap, because it represents the diferent subgraphs and connections which I need to use to reproduce the population. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Willian every time you want a different Map or List collection, create a `new` one.

Comment: I am using the debugger and I have another question. Why all Individuals are with the same HashMap<K,V> (id=42)?

Comment: @Willian I guess you only created one `Individual` object or you keep adding the same one to the values of the Map.

Comment: I found it.

Oh lord. So much time with something so stupid.

I just declared within each new individual "this.genesPlate = new HashMap<>();", and used the reference to add new shuffled ones into the this.genesPlate. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Willian now you know to check for this and you know what to look for in your debugger. An expert is some one who has made all the mistakes before ;)